# Android: Android application is going for restart if we insert wireless USB mouse

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have one android application which has Main Activity.

If we insert wireless USB mouse - Activity restart lifecycle callbacks are getting triggered from android framework. (Like, onPause - onStop - onDestroy - onCreate - onStart - onResume).

But, If we insert wired USB mouse - Activity is not restarting.

**How to prevent activity restart cycle on inserting wireless USB mouse,keyboard etc ??**

Comment: Read up on configuration changes.

Comment: @Tenfour04... onConfiguration Changes : Prevent screen size change , orientation change etc... it's not preventing USB wireless mouse insert/remove..

Comment: I think the relevant one here would be `"uiMode"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wireless mouse causes activity to recreate. Adding **navigation** in configChanges solves the problem.

```
<activity
  ...
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
/>
```

Now try to insert/remove Bluetooth mouse/keyboard etc. Activity wont recreate.